# Adding app to recent tasks list in Android (long press home button)

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I wrote my own app in Android. Everything is running ok, but when I click home button on my mobile phone I don't see my app on the list in the task manager. I see other app, but I do not see my app.

I do not know whether in this case the important, but I use also Sherlock Action Bar.
How can I add my app to task manager?
Any suggestions?

Comment: what Android version you are testing on?

Comment: Android 4.0.4 and Android 2.3;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "task manager" you mean "recent tasks", the only thing that I can think of is that [you have `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` on your activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but it does not work...I added even specially android:excludeFromRecents="false", but I still can not see, when I press home button (long press) my application, among other applications, which are available on the list.